# Flask caching multiple files in project

Tags: python, caching, flask

I'm relatively new to Flask. I have multiple files in my flask project. Up until now, I was using `current_app` if I wanted to access `app` object from outside of `app.py` file.

Now I am trying to add cache to my app with [flask-caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension. I initialize this in my `app.py`

```
from flask_caching import Cache
...
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
```

However I'm having troubles with uisng it with `views.py` file.

I have a resource class:

```
class MyEndpoint(Resource):
    def get(self):
        do_stuff_here
```

I don't know how to get `cache` object here to achieve this:

```
class MyEndpoint(Resource):
    @cache.cached(timeout=600)
    def get(self):
        do_stuff_here
```

I tried to do:

- `from app import cache` -> `ImportError: cannot import name 'cache'`
- `@current_app.cache.cached` -> `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

Part of the structure of my project:

```
|
-app.py
|
--api
  |
  -__init__.py
  -views.py
```

Comment: Can you show `imports` of  `app.py` and `views.py`?

Comment: @Quba, do you mind sharing how you ended up fixing this issue?

Comment: @MarcioPorto Sure. Will do that in a few hours

Comment: @Quba, still haven't figured out this issue. Can you give me some guidance on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @MarcioPorto I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got it working.
Just initialize Cache object in a different file:

`common/extensions.py`:

```
from flask_caching import Cache

cache = Cache()
```

and then in `app.py`:

```
from common.extensions import cache
app = Flask(__name__)
cache.init_app(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
```

Comment: You're a life-saver @Quba. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unresolved reference 'Cache' . How to install the Cache?

Comment: Life-safer for me, too. Lol

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this was because I was registering the modules of my app before I created the cache object. This creates a cyclic dependency where the module code tries to load the cache before it is created.

Register your modules in the flask app after initializing the cache. Then `from app import cache` should work fine inside your modules.